# Use of navigation controller to handle data between pages

Tags: ios, iphone

how to navigate to another page if my start page only has a button and textfield.On click of the button it has take the textfield data to another page and diplay it.I want to use navigation controller to return back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use storyboard:
name the segue between your first viewcontroller and the next viewcontroller in your storyboard and add the following method to your first viewcontroller.m:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegue"]){
         NextViewController *nvc = (NextViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
         nvc.aString = self.textField.text;
     }
}
```

Comment: Even if i add as many view controllers in my storyboard,there is only one viewcontroller.m/viewcontroller.h file present. Is it the way it should be? I am new to ios programming..

Comment: so whats the diffrence between my answer and this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewController * myVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
myVC.someProperty = someValue;    // Pass your data here
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

And in your `ViewController` class :

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString * _someProperty;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * someProperty;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize someProperty = _someProperty;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSLog(@"My Data == %@", _someProperty);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let say your first page is `Firstviewcontroller` and second page is `Secondviewcontroller`.

in `Secondviewcontroller`.h file

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *textfieldstring;
```

then in `Secondviewcontroller.m`

```
@synthesize *textfieldstring;
```

now in `Firstviewcontroller` on the click method of button just write this

```
//initialize secondviewcontroller object
secondviewcontroller *secondview=[[secondviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondviewcontroller" bundle:nil];

//Assign the textfield value to property of secondview
secondview.textfieldstring= yourtextfield.text;

//navigate to secondview controller
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondview animated:YES];
```

now in `- (void)viewDidLoad` method of Secondviewcontroller

you can get the `textfield` value in `textfieldstring` property then use this `NSString` value wherever you want.

if you using storyboard then you need to implement this method in the Firstviewcontroller.m file

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifierofsecondviewcontroller"]) {

            Secondviewcontroller *secondview = segue.destinationViewController;
            secondview.textfieldstring= yourtextfield.text;
        }
    }
```

//and this thing you still need to write in Secondviewcontroller
in `Secondviewcontroller`.h file

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *textfieldstring;
```

then in `Secondviewcontroller.m`

```
@synthesize *textfieldstring;
```

this is the tutorial that will help you definately
http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

still if any query then feel free to ask me.
Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the help.but i'm using xcode 4.5 storyboards and new to ios programming. Can you explain this with storyboard because there is no nib file here.